# jquery extract keys from json file and set to html table header

Tags: jquery, json, tableheader

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v){
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            console.log( k +' : '+ v );
            HeadKeys = '<tr><td><b>'+k+'</b></td></tr>';
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
    });
    $("#myTable tbody").html(HeadKeys + tbl_body);
});
```

I'm trying with this code, but it outputs only one key into the table row..

What I'm doing wrong?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4z2tB/)**

Comment: Can you show `data` received after ajax request?

Comment: @benjamin54 Yes, I receive data: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4z2tB/)**

Comment: You're overwriting `HeadKeys` each time instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the table headers are only examined once; also, it's good to make sure the HTML is properly escaped instead of built using strings (even though that may be faster in some cases).

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var $head = null,
        $body = $('<tbody>');

    $.each(data, function(index, obj) {
        if ($head === null) {
            // generate the first row if necessary
            $head = $('<tr>').append($.map(obj, function(value, name) {
                return $('<th>', { text: name });
            }));
        }
        // generate each row
        $('<tr>').append($.map(obj, function(value, name) {
            return $('<td>', { text: value });
        })).
            appendTo($body);
    });

    // append all the things    
    $("#myTable").append($head).append($body);
});
```

Note that relying on the specific order of object properties isn't necessarily portable; the specification of the language doesn't ensure a particular ordering should be observed. Therefore, the more stable solution is to control the order yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        HeadKeys = '<tr></tr>';
        $.each(this, function(k , v){        
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            console.log( k +' : '+ v );
            HeadKeys += '<td><b>'+k+'</b></td>';
        })
       tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
   });
   $("#myTable tbody").html(HeadKeys + tbl_body);
});
```

[Fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z2tB/1/)

Comment: Do you think that now it all works properly? Are there no keys duplicates? because in the console.log I see that nm, cty, hse, yrs, are repeated a lot of times... Do you think that they are also repeated wrongly in the result output?

Comment: Yes but what if I have a json with differents keys? It still will work?

Comment: Your code appends `'<td>...</td>'` onto `'<tr></tr>'`; that's invalid HTML by all standards.